# Showing indepedence of two random variables when $p(x,y) = p(x) \cdot p(y)$ except a constant factor?

Tags: self-study, independence, joint-distribution

During a course I attend at university, I encountered the following question:

Given is a probability distribution: 
$$p(x,y) = \lambda \eta \cdot \exp(-\lambda x - \eta y) $$
supported on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^2$. I now need to show, that $x$ and $y$ are independent. I decided to show this by using that: 
$$p(x,y) = p(x) \cdot p(y) = \int p(x,y) dx \cdot \int p(x,y) dy$$
if $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Calculating the integrals yields:

$$p(x) = - \lambda \cdot \exp(-\lambda x - \eta y)$$
$$p(y) = - \eta \cdot \exp(-\lambda x - \eta y) $$

and thus: 
$$p(x) \cdot p(y) = \lambda \eta \cdot \exp(- 2 \cdot \lambda x - 2 \cdot \eta y) $$

which is equal to $p(x,y)$ besides a constant factor in the exponent.

Does this factor matter? If not, why? If yes, my proof does not work anymore - why?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but its worth mentioning if $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for any functions $g,h$, which need not be densities, then $X,Y$ are independent. So the result is immediate since the exponential can be separated into disjoint functions of $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations of the integrals are incorrect (note that $x$ and $y$  still appear in your expressions even after integrating them out). It seems like a classical mistake of neglecting the Jacobian while integrating out $x$ and $y$ as

$$p(x) = \int p(x,y) dy = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \int \eta e^{-\eta y}dy= \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.$$

This is obtained by integrating $y$ out through the change of variable $u = \eta y$, and noting that the Jacobian is $du = \eta dy$. Analogously for $p(y)$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: $du = \eta dy$ because the function is supported only on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^2$, correct?